# Openni_launch publishes only raw image, I need compressed

Tags: kinect, openni, ros-fuerte, openni-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have two ubuntu 12.04 pcs with ros fuerte. I installed openni v1.5.4.0 libraries on both machines. Kinect is recognized by them and I'm able to display captured data on rviz.

Even though the whole process of installation was the same on both machines, after typing `roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch` one pc is publishing incomplete topic list. Looking at the simple color image topics:

this is a full list published by the first computer:

```
/camera/rgb/image_color
/camera/rgb/image_color/compressed
/camera/rgb/image_color/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/image_color/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/rgb/image_color/compressedDepth
/camera/rgb/image_color/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/image_color/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/rgb/image_color/theora
/camera/rgb/image_color/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/image_color/theora/parameter_updates
```

second one is publishing only this:

```
/camera/rgb/image_color
```

The same problem appears for /depth, /ir, and different types of /rgb.

Why the topic list on the second pc is so short? How can I make second computer to publish what I need (compressed images and data)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64852/openni_launch-publishes-only-raw-image,-i-need-compressed/) by [grzebyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3912/grzebyk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2013-06-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jiayi Liu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2718/jiayi-liu/) on 2013-06-12**:
Are the plugins installed on the second computer? http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_transport_plugins

**Comment by [grzebyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3912/grzebyk/) on 2013-06-13**:
that solved problem.
thank you!

**Comment by [grzebyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3912/grzebyk/) on 2013-06-13**:
maybe it will be better if you post it as an answer so that it will be easier to find for others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Install the image transport plugins on the second computer. http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_transport_plugins

---

Originally posted by [Jiayi Liu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2718/jiayi-liu/) with karma: 166 on 2013-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3